# Product Now Showing Up

Tags: product, catalog

I have created a product, and made it visible in Catalog and Search, and I have it in a Category. The Category is showing up, and I can navigate to it, but it has not products listed within. Do you know what's wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a simple oversight. I updated Qty and Stock Availability on this page:

[image]

I found this website to be helpful: http://www.aschroder.com/2010/07/why-are-my-magento-products-not-showing-up/